# series of list to multidimensional np array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe df.
One column is a string of numbers (as characters) divided by blank space

I need to convert it to multidim numpy array.

I thought that :

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split(" "))).values
```

would make the trick

Actually it returns an array of array....

```
array([array(['70', '80', '82', ..., '106', '109', '82'], dtype='<U3'),
   array(['151', '150', '147', ..., '193', '183', '184'], dtype='<U3'),
```

Which does not seem to be what I look what i am looking for whcih should rather look like

```
array([[[['70', '80', '82', ..., '106', '109', '82'],['151', '150', '147', ..., '193', '183', '184']....
```

First: what shoudl I do to have my daya in the second format? 
Second: I am actually a bit confused about the difference between the 2 data structures. In the end of the day a multidimensional array is an array of arrays. From this perspective it would seem that the 2 are the same structure. But I am sure I am missing somthing

EXAMPLE:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,2,3],"B":["1 2 3 4","5 6 7 8","9 10 11 12","13 14 15 16"]})

    A   B
0   0   "1 2 3 4"
1   1   "5 6 7 8"
2   2   "9 10 11 12"
3   3   "13 14 15 16"
```

This command

```
df.B.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split(" "))).values
```

gives:

```
array([array(['1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='<U1'),
   array(['5', '6', '7', '8'], dtype='<U1'),
   array(['9', '10', '11', '12'], dtype='<U2'),
   array(['13', '14', '15', '16'], dtype='<U2')], dtype=object)
```

instead of

```
 array([['1', '2', '3', '4'],
   ['5', '6', '7', '8'],
   ['9', '10', '11', '12'],
   ['13', '14', '15', '16']], dtype='<U2')
```

Question1: How do I get this last structure?
Question2: what is the difference between the 2? Technically are both array of arrays...

Comment: Create a small dataframe for input and expected output.  This will help us help you with this question.

Comment: Are the arrays different lengths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on `df.A` directly, with the parameter `expand=True` and then use `values` such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['70 80 82','151 150 147']})
print (df.A.str.split(' ',expand=True).values)
array([['70', '80', '82'],
       ['151', '150', '147']], dtype=object)
```

with your method, if all the strings contain the same amount of numbers, you can still use [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) to get the same result:

```
print (np.stack(df.A.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split(" "))).values))
```

**EDIT**: for the difference, not sure I can explain it good enough but I try. let's define

```
arr1 = df.A.str.split(' ',expand=True).values
arr2 = df.A.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split(" "))).values
```

First you can notice that the shape is not the same:

```
print(arr1.shape)
(2, 3)
print(arr2.shape)
(2,)
```

so I would say one difference is that `arr2` is a 1D array of elements that happens to be also 1D array. When you construct `arr2` with `values`, it constructs a 1D array from the serie `df.A.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.split(" ")))` without looking at the type in this serie. For `arr1`, the difference is that `df.A.str.split(' ',expand=True)` is not a serie but a dataframe, so using `values` will construct an 2D array with a shape being `(number of rows,nb of columns)`. In both case you use `values`, but actually having an array in a cell of a serie (as created in your method) will not create a 2D array.

Then, if you want to access any element (such as the first row second element) you can do it by `arr1[0,1]` while `arr2[0,1]` will throw an error because this structure is not a 2D array, but `arr2[0][1]` gives the good answer because you access the second element `[1]` of the first 1D array `[0]` in `arr2`.

I hope it gives some explanation.

Comment: nice! But what is the difference between array([['70', '80', '82'],
       ['151', '150', '147']], dtype=object) and array(array(....

Comment: A lot of sense. Thank you!